# Multiplying row in NumPy array by specific values based on another row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following list:

```
ls = [[1,2,3], [3,4] , [5] , [7,8], [23], [90, 81]]
```

This is my numpy array:

```
array([[    1,     0,     4,     3],
       [   10,   100,  1000, 10000]])
```

I need to **multiply the values in the second row** of my array by the length of the list in `ls` which is at the **index of the corresponding number** in the first row:

`10 * len(ls[1])` & `100 * len(ls[0])` etc..

The objective output would be this array:

```
array([[    1,     0,     4,     3],
       [   20,   300,  1000, 20000]])
```

Any efficient way doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list comprehesion` to find lengths and multiply it with 2nd row of array as:

```
ls = [[1,2,3], [3,4] , [5] , [7,8]]
arr = np.array([[    1,     0,     2,     3],
                [   10,   100,  1000, 10000]])

arr[1,:] = arr[1,:]*([len(l) for l in ls])

arr
array([[    1,     0,     2,     3],
       [   30,   200,  1000, 20000]])
```

**EDIT :**

```
arr[1,:] = arr[1,:]*([len(ls[l]) for l in arr[0,:]])

arr
array([[    1,     0,     2,     3],
       [   20,   300,  1000, 20000]])
```

Comment: This answer it not correct. Compare your output with by objective output. Maybe I have formed my question not clearly. Instead of 30, is should be 20, since the corresponding value in the first row is 1. Thus, `10 * len(ls[1])`  = 20 and not 30